# How to constraint route value to a valid int32 on ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Having this default route :

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default", // Route name
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        defaults: new { controller = "Application", action = "Index", id = 0 }, // Parameter defaults
        constraints: new {id = @"\d+"}
    );
```

The constraints works ok, but the id is an int on controller. So if I pass `/Controller/Action/2147483648` is a valid \d+ regex but it's not a valid `Int32`, so that returns a 500 server error and I want it to restrict so that it returns a `404`.

How can I make the constraints so it only allow valid positive int values ? which are from `0 to 2,147,483,647` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a custom route constraint like this:

```
public class MaxIntConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match (HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, 
                       RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        // just use int.TryParse because if it can't fit it won't parse
        int val;
        return int.TryParse(values[parameterName].ToString(), out val);
    }
}
```

And your route would look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default", // Route name
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    defaults: new { controller = "Application", action = "Index", id = 0 }, // Parameter defaults
    constraints: new { id = new MaxIntConstraint() }
);
```

Of course the constraint is very specific and could be spruced up with some more error checking but you get the idea.

Comment: How about using `int.MaxValue`?  But really, who cares if it parses to  a long,  just use `int.TryParse` (yes, I know you pointed this out in your comments, just reinforcing it).  But good call on the `IRouteConstraint`

Comment: You are right about using the `MaxValue` constant, that is definitely better coding practice.  I'm just going to update the answer with the `int.TryParse` solution since it is cleaner, but good call.

Comment: Thanks, the solution worked up perfect. Wondering what you are talking about using better coding practice using MaxValue constant. what's all about ?

Comment: Oh it had to do with some code I had in there before I updated my answer.  I was parsing the `id` as an `Int64` and checking that it was less than or equal to `2147483647`, and @cadrell0 made the good point to use `int.MaxValue` instead.

Comment: Pretty much that explains all :D ty both!